# Upload to central google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create an app in android that will create a file and once a button is pressed send that file to a central google drive account.

The idea is to install this app on multiple devices and have them upload the file to the same drive account.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Read about drive in the following link:
   https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/drive.html
2. Import the examples in your Android-sdk: 
   android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/drive

That should give you a head start on your project